# How do I group inputs in Local storage to be one "Event" categorized by my Date time input

Tags: javascript, html

In my app I collect information from the user and store it in Local storage using javascript like this.
    Event Name (1 to 20 characters):

```
<input type="text" id="eventname" name="eventname" required
       minlength="1" maxlength="20" size="20">
<label for="datetime">Event Date and Time:</label>

<input type="datetime-local" id="date" name="date" required
       minlength="1" maxlength="20" size="20">
<label for="eventlocation">Event Location (1 to 20 characters):</label>

<input type="text" id="location" name="location" required
       minlength="1" maxlength="20" size="20">
<label for="notes">Notes (0 to 50 characters):     </label>
<input type="text" id="notes" name="notes" required
       minlength="0" maxlength="50" size="50">
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

I then have an app.js document which puts it into local storage

```
const locationTxt = document.querySelector('#location');
locationTxt.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  localStorage.setItem('location', event.target.value);
function getSavedData() {
  console.log('location', localStorage.getItem('location'));
```

(except i have these fucntions for each of the inputs.)
How Would i go about taking all these inputs in locale storage and displaying it as 1 event that is able to be categorized by time?

Comment: If you want to be able to manipulate the values by time you will need to store the time (presumably the time they were stored?) in the data kept in local storage. Instead of just the value store an object e.g. `{value:event.target.value, date: new Date()}`. Then you have time data on which to sort/filter the elements

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to store event data in an object:

```
{
    '01-02-1900': [
        ...  // Array of events
    ],
    '01-01-1900': [
        ... // Array of events
    ],
    ...
}
```

And then using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to read/write to localStorage.

For instance:

```js
/**
 * This override localStorage in Stack Snippet
 */
const customStorage = { data: {} };
customStorage.getItem = index => customStorage.data[index] || null;
customStorage.setItem = (index, payload) =>
  (customStorage.data[index] = payload);

/**
 * Replace customStorage with localStorage below.
 */

const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

const storageIndex = "myTestStorage";

const storeInLocal = formData => {
  const { date, event } = formData;
  const toStore = JSON.parse(customStorage.getItem(storageIndex)) || {};
  if (!toStore[date]) toStore[date] = [];
  toStore[date].push(event);
  customStorage.setItem(storageIndex, JSON.stringify(toStore));
};

const readForm = () => {
  let values = {};
  inputs.forEach(({ name, value }) => {
    values[name] = value;
  });
  const { date, eventname, location, notes } = values;
  return {
    date,
    event: {
      eventname,
      location,
      notes
    }
  };
};

const outputStorage = () => {
  const storage = customStorage.getItem(storageIndex) || "";
  document.getElementById("output").innerText = storage;
};

document.getElementById("eventForm").addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = readForm();
  storeInLocal(formData);
  outputStorage();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Store form data in localStorage</title>
    <link
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <style>
      pre {
        white-space: pre-wrap;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main id="app" role="main" class="container">
      <form id="eventForm">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="eventname">Event Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input
              type="text"
              id="eventname"
              name="eventname"
              required
              minlength="1"
              maxlength="20"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="datetime">Event Date and Time:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input
              type="datetime-local"
              id="date"
              name="date"
              required
              minlength="1"
              maxlength="20"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="eventlocation">Event Location</label>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input
              type="text"
              id="location"
              name="location"
              required
              minlength="1"
              maxlength="20"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="notes">Notes</label>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input
              type="text"
              id="notes"
              name="notes"
              required
              minlength="0"
              maxlength="50"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </form>
      <h1 class="h4">Output</h1>
      <p>Hit "save" multiple times, and change the date occasionally.
      <p>
        <pre id="output"></pre>
      </p>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```